# Best way to call a method after initialising a class

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following example class:

```py
import os

class Backup(object):

    def __init__(self, path, name):
        self.path = src = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))
        self.name = name

    def read_dir():
        for path, dirs, files in ow.walk(self.path):
        ...
```

I would like to know what is the best "pythonic" way to call the method read_dir.

Should I only initialise the class and later call the method something like this:

```py
backup = Backup('/home/foo', 'my_backup')
backup.read_dir()
```

Of should I just call the method within the `__init__`, something like this:

```py
def __init__(self, path, name):
    self.path = src = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))
    self.name = name
    self.read_dir()
```

Any best practice ?

Comment: It depends entirely on your class implementation.  If `read_dir` only happens once for the class and _always_ needs to happen, calling it from `__init__` can make sense.  If it's something else you'll call into repeatedly then doing it at first-run may not make sense.  Fully subjective and dependent more on intended use than any specific python requirement.

Comment: Why is that a class at all?

Comment: The idea is to backup, encrypt , copy therefore I thought that could be better to have a class with all the methods, so that I could do something like b.backup(), b.encrypt(). b.copy(), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general 'best practice' for this, and it's not even a python specific question.

The route you take is selected for you by answering this question:

"Is the object usable before read_dir() has been called?"

- If the answer is yes, then I would leave it to the client to invoke
  read_dir()
- If there's nothing sensible they can do with the object
  until read_dir() is invoked, then call it from **init**.

The other thing to consider is whether read_dir can throw exceptions. Throwing an exception during object construction is something you generally want to avoid as it can leave things in an uncertain state.

However, you *could* invoke read_dir() lazily, by having an instance variable which records whether read_dir() has been called, and then checking it in any other method which requires it as a precondition.

Answer (score 1):

If the read_dir() method needs to be called every time an object is initialized, I would just call it in the constructor, as you did in your second example. I assume this is the case, as the class looks like it has to have a file to work with to actually function at all. If you need to reread the file in that object again for any reason, you can just call the method outside of the constructor, like you did in your first example. 'Best Practice' is very situational, especially when you are building your own methods and classes.

Otherwise, the first example you have is preferable. I cant think of a overtly 'pythonic' way of doing this. This is really object-oriented best practice and isnt language specific.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the answer depends on what you are trying to do.
If you do not care about re-usability of the class and you can guarantee that you will always perform read_dir() whenever the object is initialized, then you can include that method in the constructor.

If, however, you care about being able to reuse this Backup class in other future work you will write. It is probably best to leave that out of the constructor's implementation and design your class to be more flexible and more generic so that the caller has more control of the work flow and so they can choose when to invoke read_dir() or even not invoke it at all.